# How to change the version the package imported with conda -develop

Tags: python, conda

I downloaded a package and imported this package on conda with the command 
conda -develop package_path
(works perfectly)
Now I want to change the version of this package to an old version that is also on my computer.
On Linux and Ipython I use to change the path of the package in the .bashrc.
How can I do that with conda? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path of the package then just use

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/path/to/my/oldpackage')
import oldpackage
```

else

Just downgrade it using conda.
You can check the revisions using `conda list --revisions`

or simple just use `conda install package=1.0.0`
(here 1.0.0 is the old version of the package you want).

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the new one then install the old

```
    pip unistall package=2
    pip install package=1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

To revert

```
conda develop package_path
```

simply use

```
conda develop package_path -u
```

Then add the other version in editable mode like

```
conda develop old_package_path
```